# Unix Shell Scripting: AWK/SED Loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with entries like below:

```
root:x:0::192.168.164.164
bin:x:1:bin,daemon:192.168.164.164
daemon:x:2:bin,daemon:192.168.164.164
test:x:501:test1,test2,test3,test4:192.168.164.160
test5:x:502::192.168.164.160
```

I was looking for ways in UNIX bash/shell script by which this file can be transformed into:

```
root;0;;192.168.164.164
bin;1;bin;192.168.164.164
bin;1;daemon;192.168.164.164
daemon;2;bin;192.168.164.164
daemon;2;daemon;192.168.164.164
test;501;test1;192.168.164.160
test;501;test2;192.168.164.160
test;501;test3;192.168.164.160
test;501;test4;192.168.164.160
test5;502;;192.168.164.160
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial `awk` command. Use `:` as the input field separator, `;` as the output field separator, and then print the fields you want.

Comment: Ahh, it slightly more complicated than that. When field 4 contains a comma, you need to split it, and then repeat the print for each element of that array.

Comment: so this line `test:x:501:test1,test2,test3,test4:192.168.164.160` should be transformed into `test;501;test1;192.168.164.160
test;501;test2;192.168.164.160
test;501;test3;192.168.164.160
test;501;test4;192.168.164.160` , right?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? It would help to post your attempts so far, rather than expecting someone else to solve the whole problem for you.

Comment: I tried this - But seems to be missing something
awk -F '[:,]' '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)print$1";"$3";"$i}' filename.txt

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS=: read -r a b c d e; do
  while IFS=, read -r -a i; do
    [[ ${#i[@]} -eq 0 ]] && i=""
    for j in "${i[@]}"; do
      echo "$a;$c;$j;$e"
    done
  done <<< "$d"
done < file
```

Output:

```
root;0;;192.168.164.164
bin;1;bin;192.168.164.164
bin;1;daemon;192.168.164.164
daemon;2;bin;192.168.164.164
daemon;2;daemon;192.168.164.164
test;501;test1;192.168.164.160
test;501;test2;192.168.164.160
test;501;test3;192.168.164.160
test;501;test4;192.168.164.160
test5;502;;192.168.164.160
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your newly updated requirements:

```
awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=';' '{for(i=4;i<NF;i++) print $1, $3, $i, $NF}' file
```

Comment: This works great, Thanks! But I was playing around with another practical test case wherein the file contains another entry like:

testuser4:x:502::192.168.164.160

Then the code strips out (as expected) everything between 502 and 192.168.164.160. However,  it should show something like

testuser4;502;;192.168.164.160

Comment: Apologies - I was being callous with the test cases and the text of the question. I have corrected them now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the answer, Ed! Will keep your suggestions in mind before posting next time. This works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -F'[:,]' -lanE '$,=";"; print @F[0,2],$_,$F[-1] for @F[3..$#F-1]' file
```